# How do you take in characters at a time from a string and set up a for loop, runs the number of the second character to print out the 1st character

Tags: java

I am looking to write a function that prints out a character a certain amount of times.

I am thinking to take in the first two characters from a string and setting up a for loop that runs the number of the second character to print out the first character.

I have this so far but seem to be getting nowhere

```
 public static String output(String a, String b,String c,String d) {


    int a= Integer.parseInt(a.substring(0, 2));
      for(int i=0;i<a;i++) {


      }
```

Comment: Work it out on paper first. Get the logic right *before* trying to create code.

Comment: Can be done in a single statement in Java 11+ using regex, but that's probably beyond the scope of this assignment. `Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z])([0-9]+)").matcher(input).replaceAll(r -> r.group(1).repeat(Integer.parseInt(r.group(2))))`

Comment: What should happen if the input is something like `S11E12`?

Answer (score 1):

If you divide the length of your String by two, you can get at the base number of letter/number pairs that you have. Then you can use a for loop which increments by two each time, and pulls out the next set of two chars and processes them. Something like this:

```
public static String output(String a) {

  String output = "";
  int length = a.length();
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i+=2) {
    String tempString = a.substring(i,i+2);
    int x = Integer.parseInt(tempString.substring(1));
    for (int t = 0; t < x; t++) {
        output += tempString.substring(0,1);
      }
   }
   return output;
}
```